# Nothing returned When doing $http Promise in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make a $http.jsonp call but the promise service is returning blank without data:

Below is my Js code

```
diary.factory('SongInfo', function ($http,$q) {
return {

    //Return All Available Songs from the Database
    getAllSongs : function () {
        var defer = $q.defer();

        $http.jsonp('http://fashion.c-research.in/api/?getsongs&name=JSON_CALLBACK')
            .then(function (res){
                defer.resolve(res.data);
            })

        return defer.promise;

    },

    //Get Song using the particular ID
    getSongInfo : function (trackid) {
        var defer = $q.defer();

        $http.jsonp('http://fashion.c-research.in/api/?trackid='+trackid+'&name=JSON_CALLBACK')
            .success(function(res){
                defer.resolve(res);
            })
            .error(function (err){
                defer.reject(err);
            });

        return defer.promise;

    }
}
});
```

here is the Controller function:

```
diary.controller('PlayController', ['$scope', 'DeviceReady', 'SongInfo', function($scope, DeviceReady, SongInfo) {

        var promise = SongInfo.getAllSongs();

        promise.then(
            function (payload) {
                console.log(payload);
            }
        )

}]);
```

Nothing is being queried from the API.. Inned  way to oreate

Comment: You have a `resolve` but not `reject`. It might be returning an error which you can't catch if you don't have a `reject`. In other words, you're catching the success but not the fail/error. You should make your `getAllSongs` like the `getSongInfo` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must always send callback parameter inside `jsonp` call url,

Use `callback=JSON_CALLBACK` instead of `name=JSON_CALLBACK`

**Code**

```
diary.factory('SongInfo', function($http, $q) {
    return {
        //Return All Available Songs from the Database
        getAllSongs: function() {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            $http.jsonp('http://fashion.c-research.in/api/?getsongs&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
            .then(function(res) {
              defer.resolve(res.data);
            }, function(err) {
              defer.reject(err);
            });
            return defer.promise;
        },

        //Get Song using the particular ID
        getSongInfo: function(trackid) {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            $http.jsonp('http://fashion.c-research.in/api/?trackid=' + trackid + '&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
            .success(function(res) {
              defer.resolve(res);
            })
            .error(function(err) {
              defer.reject(err);
            });
            return defer.promise;
        }
    }
});
```